# Any good C implementation of the async-future model in C++11 or the async-await in C#?

Tags: c, asynchronous

My project has a quit a few places that need to handle the asynchronies. So I want to learn how the asynchrony can be implemented in C.

Comment: could you clarify your question? and why the title cites C++11 and Csharp but you tagged C?

Comment: C implementation of those, the title also cites C.

Comment: ah, sorry, you meant as example of functionality; got it

Answer (score 0):

I've done some asynchronous programming "back in the day".

The approach I used was to represent each asynchronous operation as a `HANDLE`, using a manual-reset event if the operation did not have an inherent `HANDLE`. Then I made a single main loop for the application that essentially just calls `WaitForMultipleObjects` and executes completion callbacks.

There are several problems with this approach:

- It is quite resource-intensive. Manual-reset event wrappers are needed quite a bit.
- It is strictly single-threaded. However, you could modify the approach to make use of thread pools; when I developed my asynchronous programs "back in the day", the OS did not yet provide a thread pool.
- It is limited to 64 outstanding asynchronous operations. I did run into this limitation, and wrote what I called an "event demultiplexer" to work around it. Essentially, you just add threads as necessary, with child threads sharing a "notification" `HANDLE` that is always in the 64 `HANDLE`s waited on by the main thread.

Comment: Ew, that entire post is windows centric.